# Autoincrement field with trigger and sequence - Check if ID is in the statement [Postgres]

Tags: postgresql, triggers, auto-increment, sequences

I´ve got this sample from another thread and it fits perfectly on what I need to know.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE AlimentosSequencia;

CREATE TABLE alimento (
  id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
 ,name VARCHAR(255));

 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION AlimentoFuncion()
 RETURNS "trigger" AS
 $BODY$
 BEGIN
   New.id:=nextval('AlimentosSequencia');
   Return NEW;
 END;
 $BODY$
 LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;

 CREATE TRIGGER AlimentosTrigger
 BEFORE INSERT
 ON alimento
 FOR EACH ROW
 EXECUTE PROCEDURE AlimentoFuncion();

 INSERT INTO alimento (name) VALUES ('lemon');
```

This is working fine! But I have to complement the function AlimentoFunction.

Is there any way to check IN THE FUNCTION if my insert statement is placing an ID?

Example:

```
INSERT INTO alimento (name) VALUES ('lemon');
```

Ok this, works... and If I do that:

```
INSERT INTO alimento (id, name) VALUES (299, 'lemon');
```

My function must check if the sequence has to be used.

I know I can set the default value of ID to be the sequence on the table creation, but I can't modify that.. I just can change the trigger function.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
if new.id is NULL then 
   New.id:=nextval('AlimentosSequencia');
end if;
```

Comment: I've tried that, but I got a message error saying that "id" doesn't exists on "new".

Comment: @ComosGuy: works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/bffd9/1 which Postgres version are you using?